# Android webview scroll does not work when the keyboard is open if Displaying content edge-to-edge

Tags: android, webview

We have an app that display content [edge-to-edge](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/edge-to-edge#kotlin) and for some core functionalities uses webview.
We have noticed that when the keyboard is open on webview the scroll stop working properly. It is impossible scroll and see the bottom of page without close the keyboard.

We create a simpler demo app (code bellow) with the same configuration and with the same issue. Considering the requirements demand content to be presented edge-to-edge is there a way to fix the webview scroll?

Activity:

```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
        //the webview scrool do not work properly with this lines
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        window.setNavigationBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(binding.toolbar) { view, windowInsets ->
            val insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            // Apply the necessary top margin
    
            val mlpHeader = view.getLayoutParams()
    
            if (mlpHeader is ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams){
    
                mlpHeader.topMargin = insets.top;
            }
    
    
    
            // Return CONSUMED if you don't want want the window insets to keep being
            // passed down to descendant views.
            WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED
        }
    
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
    
        binding.webview.loadUrl("https://www.google.com")
    
    }
```

Layout:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication.AppBarOverlay">
    
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.MyApplication.PopupOverlay" />
    
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    
    
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
    
          />
    
    
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
enter code here
```

manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

On the first image demo app is displaying contente edge-to-edge: scroll is not working properly.
On the second imagem app is not displaying contente edge-to-edge: scroll is working properly

[image: demo app is displaying contente edge-to-edge: scroll is not working properly]

[image: demo app is not displaying contente edge-to-edge: scroll is working properly]

Comment: What windowSoftInputMode do you have?  I'm not surprised at that behavior if you have PAN mode on.  Try RESIZE-  that will layout your app on top of the keyboard, so overlapping isn't possible.

Comment: I have `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` and even so the scroll is not working properly.